# Game Center leaderboard score - "20points" instead of "20 points"

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm currently testing Game Center leaderboards for my app. Everything's working fine with authenticating and submitting scores, but when I go to look at the leaderboard in Game Center, it says "200points" instead of "200 points".

Why isn't there a space between the score and the score type? And how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm an idiot - you just had to add a space before the score suffix in iTunes Connect. Leaving this up instead of deleting it, in case anyone else does the same thing :)

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. Adding space in front of the suffix then saving causes the removal of this space... anybody else seeing the same?

Answer (score 5):

So, since I understand that more people experience the same problem, and adding space in front of the label as the accepted answer suggests, does not seem to work, I figured I would post a solution that works for anyone else landing on this page:

Instead of writing `"points"` or `" points"`, I wrote `"&nbsp;points"` as the label.

This seemed to be the only thing that worked for me.