# Game Center. How to change appearance of displayed points in a leaderboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, gamekit, leaderboard

This is most likely very simple question and i have my own supposition about correct answer but i just can't verify if i'm right or not. So, in my leaderboard points are currently displayed like this `100Points` but i want it to be displayed like `100 points`. How do i insert space between `100` and `points`?

Comment: do you have anything in "Score Format Suffix" field of Leaderboard Localization section?

Comment: i don't know. this is customer's iTunes connect account

Answer (score 1):

This answer solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18204051

> Instead of writing "points" or " points", I wrote " points" as the suffix in iTunes Connect

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming as if you have created a custom leaderboard and have downloaded the scores:**

If the leaderboard points are presented using `NSString`'s then could you just subtract the last six characters from the end to leave you with the score?

`NSString *justScore = [rawScore substringToIndex:[rawScore length]-6];`